# How can I make a widget copyable?

Tags: flutter

According to a text you type in the application, it finds the appropriate emotion and then returns one of the certain emojis. I want to make these emojis copyable whatever we want. I need help on this. How can I make the emojis in the picture returned to me from the application copyable?

```
String getEmoji(String text) {
    if (text == "anger") {
      return '️ ';
    } else if (text == "joy") {
      return "  ";
    } else if (text == "sadness") {
      return "  ";
    } else if (text == "fear") {
      return " ";
    } else if (text == "love") {
      return "❤  ";
    } else if (text == "surprise") {
      return "  ";
    } else {
      return "❓";
    }
  }


 Text(getEmoji(data)+data,
     style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.green),
      ),
```

[image: Issue]

Comment: are you referring reusable snippet

Comment: @YeasinSheikh Here I want to be able to copy the emojis I return as output.

Answer (score 2):

**Wrap Your widget with SelectableText**
or
**Wrap Your Whole parent widget with selectable region**
Api Documentation For Selectable Region

[Selectable Text](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html)

[Selectable Region](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SelectableText-class.html)